# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have done some googling on this error I have an it seems to be an error in the EmployeeController but I cannot see what I have done that is different to my other templates that work. This is the error message

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError

> syntax error,unexpected ':', expecting ')'

This is my EmployeeController@edit

```
public function edit($id, $jabatan)
    {
        // gabisa pake findOrFail karena ajax
        // return response()->json($employees);
        $employees = Employee::find($id);
        if ($employees) {
            if ((int) $jabatan == 0) {
                $jabatan = Sallary::select(['id', 'nama_jabatan'])->get()->toArray();
            } else $jabatan = [];

            return $this->jsRespond(status: true, message: 'Berhasil ambil', [
                'employee' => $employees->toArray(),
                'jabatan' => $jabatan
            ]);
        } else {
            return $this->jsRespond(status: false, message: 'Data Gagal Diambil');
        }
    }

    private function jsRespond($status, $message, $others = [])
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message,
            'others' => $others
        ]);
    }
```

Can someone help me to find the fault?

Comment: Remove `status:` and `message:` from your `->jsRespond()` calls

Comment: It works, thankyou!

Comment: @brombeer - Post your comment as the answer/solution.

Comment: @JohnHanley Was about to, had to feed the cat first! ;) Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`status:` and `message:` in your `->jsRespond(...)` calls are causing the error. Remove them from the calls:

```
public function edit($id, $jabatan)
    {
        // gabisa pake findOrFail karena ajax
        // return response()->json($employees);
        $employees = Employee::find($id);
        if ($employees) {
            if ((int) $jabatan == 0) {
                $jabatan = Sallary::select(['id', 'nama_jabatan'])->get()->toArray();
            } else $jabatan = [];

            return $this->jsRespond(true, 'Berhasil ambil', [
                'employee' => $employees->toArray(),
                'jabatan' => $jabatan
            ]);
        } else {
            return $this->jsRespond(false, 'Data Gagal Diambil');
        }
    }

    private function jsRespond($status, $message, $others = [])
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message,
            'others' => $others
        ]);
    }
```